# Dealing with foreign film titles on IMDb

Tags: scraping

I've managed to scrape the data from the [Cinemetrics](http://www.cinemetrics.lv/) website, but as it is user-submitted, some of the data needed cleaning. I've been running the titles through the search function of the [OMDb API](http://www.omdbapi.com), however this struggles with certain results.

For example, the film *Meghe Dhaka Tara*. When searching with this as the query on the OMDb API I get no results. However a quick Google search, or even IMDb search, will find the film with the English title *The Cloud-Capped Star*.

I was wondering if anybody else has ever run into a similar problem and how they go about working around it?

Comment: Contact OMBd API (top right). Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

"Meghe Dhaka Tara" is a noun phrase. It makes sense for an API looking for movies to not translate the phrase as that is not its purpose. I suspect, that at most it will have some basic spell checks in place (for instance "did you mean `Megh Dhaka Tara'")

If "The Cloud-Capped Star" is indeed an english dub for the movie, then it suggests that the service provider has not linked movies to its translations.